# NHibernate not throwing exception when named query fails

Tags: .net, nhibernate, stored-procedures

I'm using a named query to execute a stored procedure (using IQuery,List) to do some insert logic. Everything seemed to be running ok except the data wasn't actually getting inserted. When I ran an SQL trace and executed to stored procedure manually I found that the stored proc was erroring due to a foreign key violation.

I'd expect NHibernate to throw some kind of exception in this situation, however it seems to ignore the error and just returns an empty list from the call. Is this a bug, related to config or something else? I'm using a fairly recent version (3.2.0.4)

Comment: What database are you using? Sql Server?

Comment: Oops, forgot to say. Yes it's SQL Server 2008

Comment: might want to show some code of how you you're calling that sp using nhibernate